# Side menu is ok in Firefox but jumps in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good morning.

Here is link to my side menu on my website: [link](http://www.odsavacky.cz/produkty/).

In Firefox works fine, shows and hide without problem. But in Chrome you can see differences, the Menu is jumping.

Thank you.

Jquery:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/') != -1 ){
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        var prev_url = document.referrer;
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + prev_url + '"]');
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').show();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').show();    
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf('/page/') != -1){
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        var page_url = window.location.href.split("/").slice(0,5).join("/");
        page_url = page_url + "/";
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + page_url + '"]');
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').show();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').show();    
    }else{  
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li').click(function(ev) {
            $(this).find('>ul').show();
            ev.stopPropagation();
        });

        var url = window.location.href;
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + url + '"]');
        $show_this_ul = $current.parent().parent();
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').show();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').show();
    }
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
```

CSS:

```
body:not(.loaded) ul.sub-menu
{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Apart from everything you should post your erroneous code first.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/142802) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Guys any idea how to help with this jumping effect?